# StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 79737200 when reading objects from a file

Tags: java, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I create a client similarity, where clients register an account (an object is created) which is stored in a file.

Objects are written to the file as required, I override the `writeStreamHeader()` method. But when I try to read them all, their file throws an exception.

Write the objects to the file here.

```
 public static void saveAccaunt(LoginAndPass gamers) {
    boolean b = true;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try{
        fis = new FileInputStream("student.ser");
        fis.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        b = false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("student.ser",true);
        ObjectOutputStream os = null;
        if(b = true){
            os = new AppendingObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            System.out.println("Объект добавлен!");
        }else {
            os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            System.out.println("Создан");
        }
        os.writeObject(gamers);
        os.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("student.ser");
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        test = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true){
            test.add(objectInputStream.readObject());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(test.get(0));

}
```

Here is the error log for the exception thrown:

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 79737200
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:866)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
>   at Registratsiya.AllGamers.main(AllGamers.java:48) 
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at Registratsiya.AllGamers.main(AllGamers.java:61)

Comment: I think that the problem is this: `if(b = true){`.  Note that you have mistakenly used `=` instead of `==`.  This means that you will be calling your `AppendingObjectOutputStream` every time, and that (presumably) means there will be no valid stream header.

Comment: And note that `if (b)` is simpler, more efficient, and cannot possibly have this problem. Don't compare booleans to true or false. They already are one or the other.